# How to get every Saturday to Thursday data on every friday using mysql

Tags: mysql

I have date column with list of dates stored  i want to get every Saturday to Thursday  data on every friday using mysql how can i do this?

i tried with this query but don't know how to do with my requirements

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- Define beginning of week as Monday
SELECT [...]
AND WorkDate >= dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate())) 
AND WorkDate <  dateadd(day, 8-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))
```

Comment: You can use trigger for that

Comment: i just want query how to write query i don't know how to get write mysql query for that logic if write a logic to get saturday to thurday  so i can run a cron job for friday

Comment: So here is two question, First is get data sat to thurs and second is execute query every friday

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this query for get data from Saturday to Thursday.

`1 Day= 86400 seconds` // so you can set INTERVAL according to day range

**Note:** This is logic only, you can manage your query. MySQL already having functions like `DAYOFWEEK(), DATE(NOW())`

I'm refering this link for futher details: [Date & Time Function in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

```
SELECT
    satwk_beg + INTERVAL 0 second sat_beg,
    satwk_beg + INTERVAL 518399 second thu_end
   FROM (SELECT (DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL daysbacktothursday DAY) satwk_beg
   FROM (SELECT SUBSTR('1234560',wkndx,1) daysbacktothursday
   FROM (SELECT DAYOFWEEK(dt) wkndx FROM (SELECT DATE(NOW()) dt) AAAA) AAA) AA) A;
```

Just execute above query and check you will get output from Saturday to Thursday.

**Here is range of other weeks**,

- `(SELECT SUBSTR('6012345',wkndx,1)` does the week starting Mon ending Sun
- `(SELECT SUBSTR('5601234',wkndx,1)` does the week starting Tue ending Mon
- `(SELECT SUBSTR('4560123',wkndx,1)` does the week starting Wed ending Tue
- `(SELECT SUBSTR('3456012',wkndx,1)` does the week starting Thu ending Wed
- `(SELECT SUBSTR('2345601',wkndx,1)` does the week starting Fri ending Thu
- `(SELECT SUBSTR('1234560',wkndx,1)` does the week starting Sat ending Fri
- `(SELECT SUBSTR('0123456',wkndx,1)` does the week starting Sun ending Sat

Comment: Little bit confused your query i have  a column name with dates in format 29-03-2016  i confused with name wkndx id it column name? and what is dt?

Comment: This is logic only for dumy data, You can manage this query according your database. and mysql having all function for you can get more details this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html First copy above query and execute in mysql then see results and learn himself with hand debugging that what happening....